# Math notation question for an algorithm

Tags: notation

I'm reviewing an algorithm and it all makes sense except for this line:

$$ \boldsymbol{b} \leftarrow (||\boldsymbol{b}|| \_{2} - \beta)_{+} \widehat{\boldsymbol{b}} $$

$\boldsymbol b$ is an $N\times 1$ vector and $\beta$ is a constant. I'm not sure what the subscript plus denotes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $(x)_+$ usually denotes $\max\{x, 0\}$. Related topics are [hinge loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) and [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)).

Comment: You found a fault in the documentation of that algorithm.  It used unexplained notation that was unknown to the reader (you).

Comment: The _2 is supposed to be a subscript 2.  Not sure why it didn't translate when posted. The bracketed b vector with the _2 is supposed to be the norm of the vector that the constant beta is subtracted from. Since the norm gives scalar I'm not sure how this gets assigned to the vector b. The subscripted plus sign I'm not sure of either. This is the last step in the algorithm to give the iteratively optimized vector b.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of posting corrections in a comment!